# GridView getting height and width of columns/rows

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to set the top gridview's column's width to the body's column width and then the left columns height to the body's coloumns height. Here is my code:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server">
        <asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableCell><asp:TableCell>
                <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" ShowHeader="false">
                </asp:GridView>
            </asp:TableCell></asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableCell>
                <asp:GridView ID="GridView3" runat="server" ShowHeader="false">
                </asp:GridView>
            </asp:TableCell><asp:TableCell>
                <asp:GridView ID="GridView4" runat="server" ShowHeader="false">
                </asp:GridView>
            </asp:TableCell></asp:TableRow>
    </asp:Table>
</div>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
</form>
```

Here is the code behinde:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
                DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
                DataTable dt3 = new DataTable();

                DataRow row;

                dt1.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Description", Type.GetType("System.String")));
                dt1.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ROXORZZOZO!!", Type.GetType("System.String")));
                dt1.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("MY", Type.GetType("System.String")));
                row = dt1.NewRow();
                row["Description"] = "WOOOO";
                row["ROXORZZOZO!!"] = "EOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO!";
                row["MY"] = "My time to shine!";
                dt1.Rows.Add(row);
                row = dt1.NewRow();
                row["Description"] = "MO!";
                row["ROXORZZOZO!!"] = "EOOOO!";
                row["MY"] = "My time to dine!";
                dt1.Rows.Add(row);
                row = dt1.NewRow();
                row["Description"] = "WOOOO";
                row["ROXORZZOZO!!"] = "EOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO!Hey Guys,Today(Thursday) I need to leave early at three to take care of some personal business.  Also, next Wednesday I’m going to be out of the office all day, taking a welding certification test.  I’ll also send out an OOO form.";
                row["MY"] = "My time to be fine!";
                dt1.Rows.Add(row);

                dt2.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Description", Type.GetType("System.String")));
                dt2.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ROXORZZOZO!!", Type.GetType("System.String")));
                dt2.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("MY", Type.GetType("System.String")));
                row = dt2.NewRow();
                row["Description"] = "Description";
                row["ROXORZZOZO!!"] = "ROXORZZOZO!!";
                row["MY"] = "MY";
                dt2.Rows.Add(row);

                dt3.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Row Numbers", Type.GetType("System.String")));
                row = dt3.NewRow();
                row["Row Numbers"] = "1";
                dt3.Rows.Add(row);
                row = dt3.NewRow();
                row["Row Numbers"] = "2";
                dt3.Rows.Add(row);
                row = dt3.NewRow();
                row["Row Numbers"] = "3";
                dt3.Rows.Add(row);
                GridView3.DataSource = new DataView(dt3);
                GridView2.DataSource = new DataView(dt2);
                GridView4.DataSource = new DataView(dt1);
                GridView2.DataBind();
                GridView3.DataBind();
                GridView4.DataBind();
                SynchGridviews(GridView2, GridView3, GridView4);
            }
        }

    protected void SynchGridviews(GridView top, GridView left, GridView body)
        {
            if (top.Width.Value > body.Width.Value)
            {
                body.Width = top.Width;
            }
            else
            {
                top.Width = body.Width;
            }

            if (left.Height.Value > body.Height.Value)
            {
                body.Height = left.Height;
            }
            else
            {
                left.Height = body.Height;
            }
            GridView2.DataBind();
            GridView3.DataBind();
            GridView4.DataBind();
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SynchGridviews(GridView2, GridView3, GridView4);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your table is snug against its surrounding divs, then you will be unable to re-size your columns/rows, so create a giant div around your table and you will be able to re-size it.